# Can not import post-install events from Branch to Google

Tags: android, ios, branch.io, post-install

We were able to import the main install event from Branch to Google, but not able to import anything **post-install**, except session start.

(Noted to the screenshot: imported events are install events for iOS and Android and session start, removed events are two test events. Install events are firing and measured without massive discrepancy.)

Tried pushing missing events multiple times. As Branch advised we even triggered the events from the back-end for the first time, but that did not help. Confirmed with Google that nothing is queing their end.

Seems like it is a know issue, any advice how to resolve? completely stuck at this point.